# Не могу загрузить приложение Instant App в Google Play

Tags: android

Ребят подскажите, создала приложение **Instant App** согласно заявленным требованиям и пытаюсь загрузить в **Google Play** Постоянно выдает одну и ту же ошибку  [image: Upload failed]

Связались с поддержкой, первый ответ был - почистите кэш, второй раз ответили:  надо чтобы приложение - `installed (apk)` было опубликовано, а потом уже грузим `zip` архив `instant`. Не помогло. Кто нибудь этим занимается? Может у кого то уже все получилось, а то не могу локализовать ошибку. То ли с их стороны проблема, то ли у меня.

Comment: А Вы подписали приложение ключем разработчика? Или пытаетесь загрузить дебаг версию?

Comment: Подписала конечно, я думаю там  четко сообщили бы об этой проблеме. Формировала apk через gradle - build - assembleRelease

Comment: Ну мало информации, Вы точно все правильно делаете? https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-instant-apps-is-open-to-all.html

Comment: Какую еще информацию дать чтобы стало много?

Comment: Вы на устройство ставили `you.apk`? Вы загружаете именно `you.apk` файл? Что еще, долбите сапорт...

Comment: Такое впечатление что Вы шутите.